# How to get data from Sessions Table Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-session

have This code

Session.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Session extends Model
{
    public function scopeAllSessions($query)
    {
        return $query->get();
    }
}
```

HomeController@index (cropped)

```
use App\Models\Session;
$uniqueViewvers = Session::all() ;

return view('pages.admin.index', ['links' => $links, 'metricks' => $metricks, 'uniqueViewvers'=>$uniqueViewvers]);
```

dd($uniqueViewvers);

```
    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1266 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Session {#1267 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "sessions"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I want to see Data from Database not current data! Maybe I have mistake with Model or maybe I don't understand how I can do this with Laravel helpers

Answer (score 0):

Delete `Session` and instead use the class which the framework provides (based on the `dd`, you're probably not even using it). Not sure if it still works with Laravel 8, but `Session::instance()->session['data']` appears more likely. If everything fails, you still could use `DB` and query table `sessions`.

Comment: `Session::instance()->session['data']` 

Result 

`ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Session\Store::get(), 0 passed in /Users/pavel/Desktop/Development/1xbetBasicIgor/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php on line 156 and at least 1 expected`

Comment: ```$sessionData = DB::table('sessions')->select('ip_address')->groupBy('ip_address')->distinct()->get();
        $uniqueViewvers = $sessionData;
        $uniqueViewvers->count();
```

Why Count() don't working?